# Map data in contentscript.js to chartjs in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chart.js

I'm building a chrome extension that displays data from an API in a chart. I've been able to get the data from each endpoint successfully. The chart library used is chartjs. I have been able to send data from background.js to contentScript.js. The challenge I'm currently facing is hooking the data to chartjs in the contentscript.js in the extension.  Below is the code.

Background.js

```
const data = {
  data1: data1,
  data2: data2,
  data3: data3
};

console.log("data", data);

// wait for tab to fully load
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status == "complete") {
    // sendMessage
    chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, (tabs) => {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0]?.id, { data: data }, (response) => {
        console.log(response);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

ContentScript.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((sender, sendResponse, message) => {
    console.log(message)
    console.log(sender)
    sendResponse("received")

    new Chart(document.getElementById("bar-chart"), {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ["Message1", "Messages", "Message3"],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "User Info",
                    backgroundColor: ["#8e5ea2", "#3cba9f", "#e8c3b9", "#c45850"],
                    data: [sender.data1, sender.data2,sender.data3]
                },
            ]
        },
        options: {
            legend: { display: true },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Your Metrics'
            }
        }
    });
    
})
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Data</title>
    <script src="./chart.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div>
        <h2>Data Analytics</h2>
        <hr>
        <div style="width: 30rem; height:20rem;display:flex;">
            <canvas id="bar-chart"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="./contentScript.js"></script>
    

</body>

</html>
```

manifest.json

```
{
    
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Data Fetch",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "description": "Get data from api",
    "permissions": ["tabs", "cookies", "storage","activeTab"],
    "host_permissions": ["https://*.site.com/*"],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "./background.js"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["https://*.site.com/*"],
            "js": ["contentScript.js", "chart.min.js"]
        }
    ],
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "index.html",
        "default_title": "Data Stats",
        "default_icon": "images/data-icon.png"
    }

  

}
```

Comment: ContentScript.js refers to a "content script" (injected in some way in some web page) or a "extension page script"? Maybe you should post **at least** the manifest file.
And also what kind of error(s) you got in console?

Comment: @Robbi, I am not getting any errors. The console is not logging any errors. I am getting the expected values. The problem is mapping the data logged in the ContentScript.js to the data=[] in the chart as such   data: [sender.data1, sender.data2,sender.data3]. I'm a bit new in creating chrome extensions

Comment: ok, you want to create a bar chart with 3 bars.  
Let us know how is the structure of sender.data1  

Are you check the right console (content script)?  
it seems you reversed the order of the parameters in the chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener callback.
Finally, I would move sendResponse before the handler closes (although I don't know how important that is)

Comment: I see you call the two .js files not only in the manifest (as a content script) but also in the html.
So it's not clear if you want to inject into a web page or if it's an extension page.

Comment: here is the structure of the message being passed to contentScript.js:

Comment: here is the structure of the message logged in contentScript.js:                
 ``` data: connections: 125
followers: 127
messages: 20 ```